# How to shorten this query by using the query builder class in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a query to move the contents from one table to another using native `php`, after I use `Codeigniter` I am confused to use Query Builder Class which is most suitable for my needs:

```
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO t_pr (ID_PR,no_pr,dept,pr_date,pr_create_date,product_name,qty,uom,Remarks,status_line,status_pr,data_entry) 
SELECT ID_PR,no_pr,dept,pr_date,pr_create_date,product_name,qty,uom,Remarks,status_line,status_pr,data_entry FROM t_pr_temp');
```

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550021/codeigniter-active-record-insert-from-one-table-to-another

Comment: Your query is correct and as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560336/8246373)  says is also correct. What you have done is a workaround.  CI  doesn't have this functionality so far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The ActiveRecord and QueryBuilder does not support `INSERT...SELECT` functionality.

With plain SQL you always can do more than via any abstraction layer (e.g. ORM, ActiveRecord, QueryBuilder, etc.), because different DB servers have different native functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Codeigniter QueryBuilder You might want to use it like this:**

```
$this->db->insert_batch( 't_pr ', $this->db->get('t_pr_temp') );
```